# How can I run cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet command

Tags: python, file, path

```
model=cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("C://Users//deniz//Desktop//yolofiles//yolov3-coco_directory//yolov3.cfg","C://Users//deniz//Desktop//yolofiles//yolov3-coco_directory//yolov3.weights")
```

here is my code but whenever i wrote this code it returns as error cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_importer.cpp:210: error: (-212:Parsing error) Failed to open NetPara
When i write the command to terminal I also got this error(cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet : The term 'cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.)
I use VC, Yolov3 and python 3.11

Comment: you can try : model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('C:\Users\deniz\Desktop\yolofiles\yolov3-coco_directory\yolov3.cfg',
                                   'C:\Users\deniz\Desktop\yolofiles\yolov3-coco_directory\yolov3.weights')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the file's path is incorrect. In my case, I never found such an error. You can store the path of the file in a variable. This is my code sample.

```js
cfgModel = "yolov3.cfg";
weightsModel = "yolov3.weights";
 
net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(cfgModel, weightsModel);
```

I hope this can help you.